# asp.net mvc jgqrid dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have problem with jqgrid when I define in colModel *edittype: 'select', formatter: 'select'*
this is my colModel:

```
colModel:
[
{ name: 'sdv_idreclamo', index: 'sdv_idreclamo', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { defaultValue: Idreclamo }, hidden: true },
{ name: 'sdv_parpieza', index: 'sdv_parpieza', align: 'left', width: '35', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { dataUrl: '@Url.Action("CargaDropDown", "raTabDatosVehiculo", new { param = "PIEZA"})', buildSelect: createSelectList} },
{ name: 'sdv_parcodclase', index: 'sdv_parcodclase', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '35', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { dataUrl: '@Url.Action("CargaDropDown", "raTabDatosVehiculo", new { param = "CODCLASE"})', buildSelect: createSelectList} }
....
],
```

When I view the web page don't show me the description only displayed the value.
for example the column sdv_pieza description is "AMORTIGUADOR" value :001, when it load the grid display 001.
I would like that it display "AMORTIGUADOR" I've added formatter: 'select' in the sdv_pieza:

```
{ name: 'sdv_parpieza', index: 'sdv_parpieza', align: 'left', width: '35', editable: true, edittype: 'select', formatter: 'select', editoptions: { dataUrl: '@Url.Action("CargaDropDown", "raTabDatosVehiculo", new { param = "PIEZA"})', buildSelect: createSelectList} },
```

When it load the grid the column sdv_pieza is it void!! doesn't me display nothing in this column

the dataUrl return good the parameters and build the select with buildSelect: createSelectList

```
createSelectList = function (data) {
   var response, s = '<select>', i;
   response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   if (response && response.length) {
      $.each(response, function (i) {
        s += '<option value="' + this.cp_idparametro + '">' + this.cp_descparametro + '</option>';
      });
   }
   return s + '</select>';
}
```

this is the image when I retrieve data to jqgrid and edit:
[image]

Comment: Is your dataUrl returning a valid select element? Have you tried building the list manually on the client side to see if it works without the call to the server?

Comment: Mark my dataUrl return a valid select element because when I add a new register in the popup window show me the "AMORTIGUADOR" but when I save the register in jqgrid show me 001

Comment: What about testing setting the Select element manually.  Via the http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules it would follow `editoptions: { value: “FE:FedEx; IN:InTime; TN:TNT” } `

Comment: Mark, I have tested setting the select element manually: editoptions: { value: "0001:BOMBA;0002:AMORTIGUADOR"} this it run correct. Now where is my error?

Comment: Well I think this narrows it down to your Select list being built via the Ajax, you are using this same call and format for other columns? Does it conform to the `<select> 
<option value='1'>One</option> 
<option value='2'>Two</option> 
...
</select>` ? Are there any characters in your display values that would break it?

Comment: Mark I've edited this post and I've attached the function createSelectList, Yes I'm using this same call and format for other columns

Comment: Do you have any display values containing text that would break the list?

Comment: I don't have values that woul break the list

Comment: Hum, the only thing I have left as issues that jump out to me to check are a data mismatch between the select list and the grid display.  I assume your JSON to the grid contains values that would match the select list for this column? It is the same function and basically the same colModel setup so some small item is breaking the build or missmatching the data.